# finding most frequent words in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix like below:

```
temp=[1     1     6;
      1     2     6;
      1     3     7;
      1     4     1;
      2     1     1;
      2     2     2;
      2     3     5;
      2     4     6;
      3     1     4;
      3     2     3;
      3     3     5;
      3     4     7;];
```

First column represent the document_id, second column represents word_id and third column represents its occurrence in the document_id.
I want to find the top 3 words in terms of their frequencies in the entire documents. Rather than just using lots of loops, what is a better way to do this in Matlab?

I have an initial idea of using:

```
sorted=sortrows(temp, 2)
```

I guess histcount or accumarray could help me but not sure how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WoW! This was the answer I was looking for:

```
sortrows(splitapply(@sum, sorted(:, 3), findgroups(sorted(:, 2))), -1)
ans =

    17
    14
    11
    11
```

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/splitapply.html

**Update1: actually NOT. Because it doesn't tell me which word_id from the second column are creating this

**Update2: while I can get the highest frequency word_id, I cannot get the top 3 frequency word_ids using the following method:

```
>> [index, max_val] =max(splitapply(@sum, sorted(:, 3), findgroups(sorted(:, 2))))

index =

    17


max_val =

     3
```

Correct final answer:

```
>> [frequencies, original_positions] = sort(splitapply(@sum, sorted(:, 3), findgroups(sorted(:, 2))), 'descend')

frequencies =

    17
    14
    11
    11


original_positions =

     3
     4
     1
     2
```

Comment: you could call `sort` instead of `max` to get the top 3 ids.

Comment: requires ≥ R2015b

Comment: You self-admit that the first code snippet is wrong, and that the second works, but the third is best. To avoid confusing future readers, would you mind removing the first two snippets and explaining the third; either with plain text or comments?

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in a solution with [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) (as you expected), there you go:

```
[Pos, ~, ind] = unique(temp(:,2));   %Finding unique word IDs (unsorted) 
freq = accumarray(ind, temp(:,3));   %Frequencies             (unsorted)
```

To get the top 3. Sort the frequencies in descending order and extract the values at first three indices (or sort in ascending order and extract the values at last three indices).

```
PosFreq = sortrows([Pos freq], 2, 'descend');  %Sorting according to frequencies
Top3PosFreq = PosFreq(1:3,:);                  %Extracting top three frequencies
```

---

*Result:*

```
Top3PosFreq =

     3    17
     4    14
     1    11
```